# Google App Engine jinja2: ImportError: No module named _markupsafe

Tags: google-app-engine

If you follow the Python2.7 getting started guide, you get to the templating part [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates.html). For me on Ubuntu 11.10 I would get a horrible stack trace that ended with:

```
  File "/home/fratrik/code/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1571, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 587, in <module>
    from jinja2._markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: No module named _markupsafe
```

The important part is actually at the top:

```
ERROR    2011-11-13 00:48:12,767 dev_appserver_import_hook.py:1386] Third party package markupsafe must be included in the "libraries:" clause of your app.yaml file in order to be imported.
```

Answer (score 46):

The answer is to add the following to your `app.yaml`

```
libraries:                                                                      
- name: jinja2                                                                  
  version: latest                                                               
- name: markupsafe                                                              
  version: latest
```

(for python2.7)

Answer (score 1):

You can import the jinja2 module that is coming with the app engine sdk.
Add the path of `google_appengine/lib/webapp2` and `google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2_extras` directories to your `$PYTHONPATH`.

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import jinja2
```

along with the yaml entries.

Comment: This doesn't import jinja2. webapp2_extras.jinja2 is wrapper.

Comment: sudo easy_install jinja2 to download it to you local libraries. You are right :)